# How to See Who Liked a Sharepoint List Item

Tags: 2013, rating, like

Is there any way that I can see who liked a sharepoint item outside of the "hover the smiley face" and a popup shows the users who liked it?

Ideally, I would like to export every single user who has liked an item within the entire list to something like excel, where I can analyze it.

Comment: Similar: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67633/get-list-item-likes-using-jsom-or-rest-apis and this one http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10480/how-to-fetch-list-of-users-who-have-taged-a-list-item-with-i-like-it-tag

Comment: Here's how to see who liked a SharePoint List Item: http://www.itsupportforum.net/topic/how-to-see-who-liked-a-sharepoint-list-item/ Easy :)

Comment: @BarryManly yes, I've seen how to do that. Unfortunately that doesn't allow me to do anything meaningful when I'm looking at a list with 1000+ items...

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late but it might help others:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".ms-comm-likesMetadata").mouseover(function() {
        var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List name')/Items("+ parseInt(this.nextElementSibling.id.split('-')[1])+")?$select=LikedBy/Title&$expand=LikedBy"
        $.when($.ajax({
           url: endpoint,
           async:false,
           method: "GET",  
           headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
           success: function (data) {           
           if(data.d.LikedBy.results.length > 0)
           {
              for(var pp=0;pp<data.d.LikedBy.results.length;pp++)
              {              
               alert(data.d.LikedBy.results[pp].Title);
              }
           }
           }, error: function (err)  {

           }
      })).done(function(data) {              
      });   
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SP Designer workflow to do this.  Research some examples of using the Call HTTP web service action in SP Designer for more specifics, but here is a summary:

Call HTTP Web Service (HTTP Get) to your list, example
HTTP web service URL: *yoursite*/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Posts')/Items?$select=LikesCount,LikedBy/Title&$expand=LikedBy&$filter=Title eq ('Title*')

Title*= set equal to current item title

Then Get Item from Dictionary:  Get (0)/LikedBy/results output to another dictionary variable (LikedByDic).

Count items in above step and then create Loop to run through the second dictionary.

Within the Loop, Get (CountVariableUsedInLoop)/Title from the second dictionary (LikedByDic) output to string variable(UserLikedBy)(this will be the user who liked the post).

I created another string variable (AllUsers) within the loop to add each user:
Set Variable: AllUsers to [%Variable:UserLikedBy%];[%Variable:AllUsers%]

Then a final step after the loop stage to email me the value of this string variable (AllUsers).

Answer (score 0):

Srujans answer worked like a charm. I made a minor modification to be able to show the response side by side with the list. Place the follwoing next to you list in a script editor.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ms-comm-likesMetadata").mouseover(function () {
        var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('YOUR LIST NAME')/Items(" + parseInt(this.nextElementSibling.id.split('-')[1]) + ")?$select=LikedBy/Title&$expand=LikedBy"
        $.when($.ajax({
            url: endpoint,
            async: false,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                // console.log(data.d.LikedBy.results.length);
                if (data.d.LikedBy.results.length > 0) {
                    $("#user").empty();
                    var users = [];
                    for (var pp = 0; pp < data.d.LikedBy.results.length; pp++) {
                        var user = data.d.LikedBy.results[pp].Title;
                        users.push(user);
                        // console.log(users);
                    }
                    users.sort();
                    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                        nameList = "<li>" + users[i] + "</li>";
                        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML += nameList;
                    }
                }
            }, error: function (err) { }
        })).done(function (data) { });
    });
});

</script>

<ul id="user" style="list-style-type:none;"></ul>
```